# Variable does not pass to the view from the controller

Tags: angularjs, controller, scope

I am new in AngularJs and can not figure out with such problem.

I try to change the variable in the scope that unassuming way.

```
.controller('AuthController',  function($scope,Auth) {
      $scope.submit = function() {
          Auth.login($scope.username,$scope.password, function(result){
              $scope.result = result   
          });
      }
        })
```

Where Auth is a service which makes GET request to server and gets response like this:

```
{ 'status': 1,  'message': "User does not found!"}
```

But my variable does not refresh in my template. When I put this

```
$scope.result = { 'status': 1,  'message': "User does not found!"}
```

outside the function $scope.submit. It works fine.

This is my routing.

```
$stateProvider
    .state('index', {
        url: "/",
        templateUrl: "/static/templates/_index.html",
    })
```

My template is.

```
<div class="alert" >{{ result.message }}</div>
```

Can someone explaine me what do I do wrong?
Thanks.

This is my service.

```
function login(username, password, callback) {
  return $http.post('/api/login/', {
    username: username, password: password
  }).success(callback);

}
```

After inserting

```
Auth.login($scope.username,$scope.password, function(result){
$scope.result = result   
console.log($scope.result);
```

I see correct data in my firebug.

Object { status=1,  message="User does not found!"}

$scope.$apply(); - gives me Error: [$rootScope:inprog] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.0/$rootScope/inprog?p0=%24digest

Comment: try `$scope.$apply();` after `$scope.result = result;`

Comment: What does `console.log(result)` in your callback before `$scope.result = result` say?

Comment: Are you calling the submit function somwhere?

Comment: Does Auth.login() return a promise or something? Can we see your Auth service please?

Comment: This is my service.

     function login(username, password, callback) {
       return $http.post('/api/login/', {
         username: username, password: password
       }).success(callback);
  
     }

Comment: I call submit from template this way <form ng-submit="submit()">

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure `Auth.login()` doesn't return a promise. It looks like it wants to, in which case try...

```
Auth.login($scope.username, $scope.password)
    .then(function(result){
        $scope.result = result   
    });
```

Hard to say without seeing your Auth service.

Answer (score 0):

If your `Auth.login()` returns a `promise` you can use its `then` function to define success and error handler e.g:

```
    Auth.login($scope.username, $scope.password)
        .then(function(result){// success handler
            $scope.result = result  
            $scope.$apply(); 
        },function(error){// error handler
            console.log(error);
    });
```

However if it makes an `ajax` call and does not return a `promise`, you can use `$q` service to return a promise by yourself. Here's how you can do it:

```
 var deferred = $.defer();
 deferred.resolve($.ajax({
// Your ajax call
}));
```

You can return promise using `return deferred.promise`.

**Note** : Make sure you inject `$q` service in your `Auth` service.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was decided by changing

```
$scope.result = result.data;
```

on

```
$scope.blabla = result.data;
```

And after that magic my template finally show me {{ blabla }} variable.

Angular dose not live up my expectation :-(